# rails: create a single table without id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've just generated my first scaffold in rails. Now, I don't want my table to have a field named "id". Instead I want it to be named "uid" which will be an arbitrary string. But I can't seem to get my head around how this is to be done. Especially with managing routes. I've managed to set :id=>false and define "uid" as the primary key but the controller fails because it still tries to lookup by id. How do I handle this?

Also, anything else I'm not aware of that might blow?

And, I know rails is all about convention and all and I must not try to go against "the rails way", but I really want this thing to work this way.

Answer (score 4):

In your migration update your code like this:

```
create_table :table_name, :primary_key => :uid do |t|
...
end
```

And your model should include this line:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :uid
end
```

All will be working same as with normal id column.

Model.find will find by uid, not id and etc ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find records by doing:

```
@record = Model.find('foo')
```

or

```
@record = Model.find_by_uid('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that in your migration file you have:

```
create_table :table_name, :primary_key => :uid do |t|
...
```

then insert in your model:

```
self.primary_key = "uid"
```

and find your record as John Topley says:

```
@record = Model.find('foo')
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

**The existing answers are, although great for older versions, outdated, so here is the update:**

(Built on top of retro's +1 answer:)

Migration:

```
create_table :table_name, id: false, :primary_key => :uid do |t|
...
end
```

Model:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key= :uid
end
```

**Note:** I believe this change goes back to ~ rails 3, however I am not 100% certain about this.

Happy codin .